# All SQL Server instances from the network using ManagementObject

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to get list of SQL Server instance names and the version and edition on my network. I have tried with following code

```
string NamespacePath = "\\\\.\\ROOT\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ComputerManagement12";
string ClassName = "SqlServiceAdvancedProperty";

// Create ManagementClass
ManagementClass oClass = new ManagementClass(NamespacePath + ":" + ClassName);
string s = string.Empty;
string instancename = string.Empty;

// Get all instances of the class and enumerate them
foreach (ManagementObject oObject in oClass.GetInstances())
{          
    instancename = instancename + Convert.ToString(oObject["ServiceName"]);
}
```

Can I get the all instance of SQL Server, its version and edition from the network using above code?

Can anyone help me to get the list of SQL Server instances and editions?

Comment: the result of output SQLCMD -L (or osql -L) lists all servers in local network.  If you have logins to every server, found in list / your domain login for every server found in list is valid, you can just execute query select @@version on each server. MMC calls, as in your example, require rights too

Comment: We don't have the credentials of the sqlserver. We just need to get list of sqlserver instance name, version and edition. Can any one knows how can we get the information using WMI and c# code?

Answer (score 1):

see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032.aspx

Only thing to mention is the article code sample uses the WMI provider for SQL Server 2008 to detect all SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2005 instances. For every instance detected, the code will list the edition and version of each instance in the results. 
You'll have to check for ComputerManagement11 for SQL 2012, ComputerManagement12 for SQL 2014 and ComputerManagement13 for SQL 2016.